# Install php 5.6 on Debian Wheezy on Armel

Tags: debian, php, arm

I'm working with an ARM server, and it has Debian Wheezy on it. Poor choice, I know, I didn't install it.

I've (loosely) followed [this guide](http://www.devops.zone/tricks/install-php-5-6-on-debian-wheezy/) and added this to sources.list:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all
```

But now when I to update repos, I get error

```
Fetched 6235 B in 17s (363 B/s)                                                                                                                                              
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.dotdeb.org/dists/wheezy/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'all/binary-armel/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.dotdeb.org/dists/wheezy-php56/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'all/binary-armel/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong, but what? All I really want is to get PHP 5.5 or 5.6 on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I cant fit both these links in a comment, but I believe you've added the repository incorrectly:

For PHP56, add:

> http://packages.dotdeb.org/dists/wheezy-php56/

For all Wheezy, add:

> http://packages.dotdeb.org/dists/wheezy/

Comment: that didn't help, but I think the problem is dotdeb doesn't work for ARM. Any other ideas?

Comment: I got the links above by browsing the repository using Chromium, and you were right.  There are only 2 supported arches, so I Googled for ARM support and only found [PHP5 in the official repositories](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/php5), but that's at 5.4